# Beta testing with internal testers for iOS 8

Tags: testing, app-store-connect, ios8, testflight, beta-testing

I'm having trouble with setting up a beta test with internal testers using iTunes Connect and TestFlight.

I've added users as internal testers inside iTunes Connect, but how do I distribute the app to them? Inside Xcode I don't find any option for distributing to beta testers.

Answer (score 24):

In response to @haupman's issue.

It seems that trying to install, when accepting the invite in the gmail app, on an iOS device, won't always work.

The workaround was to forward the email to an address that is synched to the iOS mail app and then click on the links from inside.

Comment: Yes it seems that only links opened from the iOS mail app work

Comment: On my mac, copying the link from the email into the 'notes' app, which is synced through iCloud, and then opening the link from notes on the device gets around the problem.

Comment: OMG the ridiculous hoops to jump through in the iOS ecosystem will never cease to amaze me... This was my problem too, need to open from native email client now gmail or web mail....

Answer (score 4):

As Fluffhead said, Gmail app won't work, since it opens Chrome for the link, which has no use.

Two options to accept the internal tester invitation in a mail from iTunes:
1) Use iOS Mail to click the link in the mail, then iOS Mail will open Safari automatically.
2) If iOS Mail is not available, copy the link and paste it to Safari. For example, you can use Gmail to click the link, copy the link in Chrome, and then paste it to Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Its the issue with Gmail definitely.

> Forward the invitation mail to one of your mailID configured on your
>   Mail app on iOS device.
>
> Open the link now from your apple mail app.

The link works now.